how to Install git package using yum on Storage server
The Nautilus development team shared requirements with the DevOps team regarding new application development.—specifically, they want to set up a Git repository for that project. Create a Git repository on Storage server in Stratos DC as per details given below:
Install git package using yum on Storage server.
After that create a bare repository /opt/blog.git (make sure to use exact name).
Install git package using yum on Storage server.
After that create a bare repository /opt/blog.git (make sure to use exact name).


First login to the storage server (ex: ssh user@servername)
once login to the server use the command "sudo yum install git" to install
git in cent-os
check the git installation using the command "git --version"
To create a bare Git repository named /opt/blog.git, you can use the
following commands:
sudo su,
mkdir -p /opt/blog.git,
git init --bare /opt/blog.git

